# Read text file and save numbers to intergers

Tags: c#, streamreader, readline

I have a text file and I need to save specific items by type. So the numbers I have to save as integers and specific words as strings.

This is what I have so far:

```
string line;
int sizeOne;
int sizeTwo;
StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Asus\Documents\text.txt");
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
file.Close();

Console.ReadKey();
```

The .txt file is:

```
[header]
name = "Simple Maze"
size = 9,10
[/header]

[level]
xxxxxxxxx
x..xsx..x
x.xx.xx.x
x.......x
x..x.x..x
x..xxx..x
x.......x
x.xx.xx.x
x.x.t.x.x
xxxxxxxxx
[/level]
```

Comment: What is it you are having issues with?

Comment: If you have a mix between numbers and strings you can use int.TryParse(string, out number), this method returns true or false if the string is parseable to int. But your file seems to have only strings, except the third line.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are looping through the lines you can check at each line whether it [Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) a certain string.

If you have found this line then you can twist the values that you need by using the [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) method

If you have carved the values out of the file then you should [Convert them to integer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b(v=vs.110).aspx).

This is basically the algorithm in words. Now it's up to you to mould it into code.

You can find examples to each of the steps here on StackOverflow. Have fun